# how to use our own dns server in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, centos, bind

Hello I have installed the DNS bind in aws linux machine.

And I want to use this DNS aws server to all my remaining aws server.

Whether it is possible to that ?

So I want to use my DNS server instead of AWS DNS

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? What are you trying to solve that Route53 Private Hosted Zones doesn't solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a creak for this. But few peoples already mentioned using Private DNS in R53. Im also preferring the same.

But for this, You need to use a custom DHCP set for this.

1. Disable AWS DHCP and create your own DHCP server.
2. Create a new DHCP option set and use your DNS and give the DHCP IP which your created in the previous step.
3. Then launch a new instance, it'll get the IP from your own DHCP and DNS.

Comment: Hello SQLadmin thanks for your reply. 
1. Disable AWS DHCP and create your own DHCP server.

Comment: Hello SQLadmin as per your reply I have displayed the DHCP and created my own DNS server and when I launched the new instance it pointing to my DNS, but I cant nslookup, dig the domain 

[root@ip-172-31-xx-xxx ec2-user]# dig ns1.xxxxxxx.xyz

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-51.amzn2.2 <<>> ns1.xxxxxxx.xyz
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Comment: Thanks SQLadmin finally I fixed the issue Now I can able to manage the DNS in AWS

Answer (score 1):

What's your question? You can use your DNS instead Route53.
Just assign the elastic IP address to your EC2 instance and update your DNS records to new IP.

Comment: I have created the new instance and installed the Bind in AWS linux ami. and I have update my DNS like ns3.domain.com

Now what I want his to use this DNS to for remaining ec2 instance instead AWS DNS server

Comment: It's the general question about "How to configure DNS" and not depend on AWS. Make sure to open port 53 on the security group.

Comment: Yes I have opened all the ports in security group